# Exposure onset unknown in time to event analyses

Tags: modeling, survival, censoring

If I want to model the time to an event (cancer) in a group of patients exposed to e.g. a cancerous substance. I now have some people where I do not know if they were already exposed to the substance before the study started, would I call this left censoring? How would I model such an unknown process?